# New line in eclipse regex replacement

Tags: regex, eclipse

I have letter pattern

```
(\w+)
```

and I want following replacement:

```
match
match
```

I was trying `$1\n$1` but it's not working. How can I replace word with some multiple line text?

**Example**

I have:

```
foo
```

and I want:

```
foo{
   foo 
}
```

Comment: Elaborate more with examples

Answer (score 0):

**You missed `\r` use it along with `\n`**.

**In general:**

Find: `(\w+)`

Replace with:: `$1 {\r\n\t\t$1\r\n}`

---

**In specific:**

Find: `foo`

Replace with: `foo{\r\n\t\tfoo\r\n\t}`

> Note: Use appropriate number of tab characters